# How to prevent a datasource from loading

Tags: database, spring, jboss, datasource

I have two datasource in my app-ds.xml file. I want only one to load at a time. Because loading both will take much cpu resources. It means that I will have a flag somewhere that will determine which database should load. Both these database will contain roughly the same data, the only difference is one is live(which is used by other applications as well), and the other one is a local copy(we can modify everything here). Please note that separating the database into different environments is not the answer we hope for. Because we have both databases for every environments(most likely DEV and TEST)

Any idea on how I should do this will be very helpful.

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/dataSource/database1" pool-name="database1">
        <connection-url>jdbc:sybase:Tds:host:port/schema</connection-url>
        <driver>sybase</driver>
        <pool>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
            <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
            <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
            <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>user</user-name>
            <password>password</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>

    <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/dataSource/database2" pool-name="database2">
        <connection-url>jdbc:sybase:Tds:host:port/schema</connection-url>
        <driver>sybase</driver>
        <pool>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
            <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
            <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
            <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>user</user-name>
            <password>password</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss, Datasources always bound and register the persistent context when deploying.

It does not take much memory when deploying.

You must remove the local datasource when your application going to production.